# How to see repositories?

Tags: git, ssh, repository

I have the key and I know the server name. But I don't know how to determine the repository namе.

```
git@git.domain.com:repo_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally just find out what repo I want to use on the web. The format I use for ssh with git is:

`git@git.domain.com:<username>/<repo-under-user>`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the .git to the repository name at the end.
Since you mentioned keys, I am assuming you are using the SSH method.
You can pull a repository like this (for example):

`git clone git@github.com:Circular-Studios/Dash.git`